# A word for “the piece that was missing.”

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, phrase-meaning

I’m looking for a word or short phrase in any language that means the piece that was missing, or the thing that was missing. Like, feeling whole. If you have a recipe and it’s missing one thing. Or a montage but there’s one thing missing before it’s complete. What is that missing piece called or referred to as?

Thanks!

Comment: "Missing puzzle piece" is used in several contexts.

Comment: Do you want to refer to it before it’s identified or after?

Comment: In situations (especially plays or stories), the missing thing is often called "The McGuffin" (ma-GUFF-in). Like the One Ring. It's only important because it's missing. Searching for the McGuffin is a standard trope that unifies many stories.

Answer (score 4):

"Missing piece" works fine. Or you could use "lacuna" which means a blank space or a missing part.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can use any of these words

- Missing piece
- Final piece
- Last bit
- Final clue

Whatever you do O' seeker of “the piece that was missing.”, remember, "there is no secret ingredient" from [Buddhist memes, https://imgflip.com/tag/buddhism](https://imgflip.com/tag/buddhism)

Answer (score 1):

Your question deals with the lack of something that would be expected to be present (an ingredient in a recipe, a component of a montage). Similar examples might be the lack of a logical step in an argument, the lack of a tool in a purchased set of tools). It does not deal with the mere absence of something, such as a gap in a range of mountains, the lack of trees in a desert.

You may therefore describe your examples as **omissions**

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/omission)
> *omission*
> something neglected or left undone
> *There are a few omissions in the list.*

You write of *one* missing item rather than several. Use the definite article and to *the omission* rather than *an omission* to make clear that there is only one.

“The omission in this puzzle is the piece with the red ball”.
“The olive oil is the omission in this recipe”